# How do I lock my Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I have found some Facebook accounts if someone is not my friend, it shows "This profile is locked". I want to do same with my Facebook account. How can I do that?

I have seen in other's accounts a tab written "Do you want to lock your profile"? under their profile picture.  But on my iPhone I do not have any tab like that.

Answer (score 2):

Locked profiles is likely a new feature being rolled out, you can read more about it on this Facebook support page: [How do locked profiles work](https://www.facebook.com/help/196419427651178?helpref=popular_topics). In particular note the top:

> Locked profiles aren't available to everyone yet.

The following link has been published in a number of places as being the page to let you do this, but I don't have Facebook to test it:
https://m.facebook.com/private_sharing/home_view/?entry_point=profile_blue_pill